# Performance counter da mas bajo en RAM que administrador de tareas

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy haciendo un medido de CPU y RAM con arduino para que lo escriba en un LCD.

El problema es que cuando quiero medir la RAM con performance counter me da mas bajo que el administrador de tareas y open hardware monitor

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
//using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices;

namespace Performance_Counter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        String COMPort = "COM5";
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                serialPort1.PortName = COMPort;
                serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
                serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
                serialPort1.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), "One");
                serialPort1.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), "None");

                serialPort1.Open();
                progressBar1.Value = 100;
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            lblCOMPort.Text = COMPort;

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string CPUUsage = "CPU:" + performanceCounterCPU.NextValue();
            string RAMUsage = "RAM:" + performanceCounterRAM.NextValue();

            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.WriteLine(CPUUsage + "         ");
                serialPort1.WriteLine(RAMUsage + "         ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**performanceCounterCPU**

CategoryName: Procesador

CounterName: % de tiempo de procesador

InstanceName: _Total

**performanceCounterRAM**

CategoryName: Memory

CounterName: % Committed Bytes in use

InstanceName:

Answer (score 1):

La memoria no se reserva por bytes sino por bloques. Esto quiere decir que el Sistema Operativo le da a un proceso más memoria de la que necesita.

Si, por ejemplo, los bloques fuesen de 100B y tu aplicación necesita 101B para funcionar, el SO le asignará dos bloques de memoria a tu aplicación.

La memoria se gestiona así por varios motivos:

- La gestión de bloques es mucho más sencilla que la gestión de reservas individuales
- Este mecanismo posibilita que reservas consecutivas de memoria por parte de una misma aplicación acaben en posiciones contiguas de memoria. Esta localización de la memoria favorece el trabajo de la memoria caché
- Reduce la posibilidad de que exista fragmentación de memoria a nivel del Sistema

En principio existen mecanismos de segmentación y de paginación de memoria, esto es solo una simplificación.

Pues bien, en tu caso, `PerformanceCounter` es una clase de C#, es decir, se ejecuta en el entorno de la aplicación. En ese plano tiene acceso a todas las reservas de memoria que se han realizado, es decir, es capaz de decirte exactamente cuantos bytes de RAM está manejando la aplicación.

El administrador de tareas, por otro lado, no sabe cómo gestiona la memoria cada aplicación. Esta aplicación no es capaz de decirte cuántos bytes de memoria RAM estás usando en un momento dado. En cambio sí es capaz de indicarte cuanta memoria ha reservado el Sistema Operativo. El administrador de tareas mira cuántos bloques de memoria tiene asignados tu aplicación.

Es por eso que la clase de C# normalmente te dará un valor inferior al que obtienes desde el administrador de tareas